# How to get 'translate' text value from an Angular tag using selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to get translate text value from an Angular tag using selenium Java. Specifically saying, I want the value coming in translate tag

```
<h5 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title"> 
<span translate="EMAIL_MSG"/>
Please enter your email address. </h5>
```

The translate tag is returning value "An email with instructions to reset your password will be sent to test.test@test.com . Please check your email shortly."

Comment: .//span[text(), 'Please enter your email address']

Answer (score 1):

`translate` is an attribute, not a tag. Use `getAttribute()` method to get the value

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myModalLabel > span")).getAttribute("translate");
```

Comment: Actually I have tried it already it's just returning True or False,but  not the whole message.

Comment: same for me. it's not in the list of things that return boolean in the selenium javadoc. i'd really like to test for the presence of the expected translation key, not the actual text. dang it.

Comment: actually just figured out if you use "Translate" with a capital T as the attribute name, it works just fine. it'll return the translate key instead of "true". found here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4331

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what are you asking here by getting translate text value. Did you try simply using `getText()`? 
This should simply return you the text you need.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModalLabel']/span")).getText();
```

Comment: There is no text inside the `SPAN`.